# jQuery submit() not working in IE when an <input type="file"> is in the form

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I want to use an submit input to trigger a click in the file input and also to submit the form itself. Clicking in the submit button will open a file picker window, and after it closes the form will be submitted. I'm using this code:

```
<?php
  var_dump($_FILES);
  echo "<br>".time();
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#uploadform").submit(function() {
        $("#file", this).click();
        return false;
      });

      $("#uploadform #file").change(function() {
        $(this).closest("#uploadform").unbind('submit').submit();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="uploadform" name="uploadform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; visibility: hidden">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In FF and WebKit this works fine, but in IE the form is not submitted when calling submit(). You can tell because the current time generated by PHP at the top of the page doesn't change. I tried submitting the form inside a setTimeout() call, but no dice. I have no errors in the console or anywhere else.

Comment: @PauloTomé: tag-linking arbitrary keywords like this is super-distracting. Please limit the use of these links to terms where it's actually helpful to folks with this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE has a safety check, where if a user has not physically clicked on the file upload button themselves, then it will not submit the form.

You cannot use javascript to do it for them.